# Can't enqueue newer style.css changes in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't load newer style.css changes I've made into my wordpress theme, its pulling an older version of that file / ignoring any new changes I've made/saved.

In functions.php under the root of my theme folder "humescores" I have this to enqueue my stylesheets

```
function humescores_scripts() {
        //Enqueue Google fonts: Source Sans Pro and PT Serif
        wp_enqueue_style('humescores-fonts','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,400i,700,700i|Source+Sans+Pro:400,400i,600,900');

    //Connects style.css
    wp_enqueue_style( 'humescores-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'humescores-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'humescores-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'humescores_scripts' );
```

Directory Structure

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
function humescores_scripts() {
        //Enqueue Google fonts: Source Sans Pro and PT Serif
        wp_enqueue_style('humescores-fonts','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,400i,700,700i|Source+Sans+Pro:400,400i,600,900');

    //Connects style.css
    wp_enqueue_style( 'humescores-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), time());

    wp_enqueue_script( 'humescores-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'humescores-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'humescores_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wp_enqueue_style('YOUR_NAME_STYLE', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
```

Comment: what's wrong with my enqueue style though `wp_enqueue_style( 'humescores-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );` doesn't it do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

`First` make sure you write the right path to call `style.css file` you can call `style file with two method`

1. `wp_head()` function in the head of the page or  `call the function name in the header page that call style files or scripts files`

   In your case your function name is  `humescores_scripts()` call this
   function in the header page

   ```
   <?php humescores_scripts(); ?>
   ```

you can also call the main style file in the header page

```
<?php wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );?>
```

After making sure of this press `shift+f5` or `fn+f5` from keyboard to refresh and redownload the cache of files in browser

Comment: ah okay I was actually wandering what the force purge cache shortcut button was. what's wrong with my enqueue style though `wp_enqueue_style( 'humescores-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );` doesn't it do the same thing?

Comment: I edit my answer call your function name in `the header page` @Kagerjay

Answer (score 0):

found problem

google chromium decided to ignore changes *(because the changes were so small, all I edited was an `h1` tags color)* so I cleared out my browser cache, and refreshed page, it works now

https://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens

Comment: Loading up Google Chrome & Google Chromium after the fact, via browser-sync, I did not clear chromes cache and it still has original problem, but chromium does not after clearing cache, so this is how i know its a browser issue